# Why does datetime.strptime throw an error when run with Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to write a page in Django which gets start and finish times for a certain task using JavaScript and POSTs it using AJAX. Since JavaScript doesn't seem to have a very good way of formatting dates, I'm sending just sending a date string like `Fri May 13 2016 22:00:56 GMT-0600 (MDT)` to be parsed as a string by Python.

Here is my function for parsing the string:

```
def get_js_date(string):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)')
    return date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

And the view uses it like so:

```
def review_new(request):                                                                                                                                                                                            
    if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                                                    
        review = Review(                                                                                                                                                                                            
            user = request.user,                                                                                                                                                                                    
            start = get_js_date(request.POST.get('start')),                                                                                                                                                         
            finish = get_js_date(request.POST.get('finish'))                                                                                                                                                        
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        review.save()
```

When I import the function in the Python REPL, it works just fine:

```
>>> from checks.utilities import get_js_date
>>> get_js_date('Fri May 13 2016 22:00:56 GMT-0600 (MDT)')
'2016-05-13 22:00:56 MDT'
```

But when I run it through `./manage.py shell`, it breaks:

```
>>> from checks.utilities import get_js_date
>>> get_js_date('Fri May 13 2016 22:00:56 GMT-0600 (MDT)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phin/virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "/home/phin/virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/phin/grappleshark/checks/utilities.py", line 4, in get_js_date
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Fri May 13 2016 22:00:56 GMT-0600 (MDT)' does not match format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)'
```

Something about the Django environment seems to be breaking everything, and I can't seem to find what it is. Am I missing something obvious? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the moment.js library to format dates in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are hitting [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue22377) in Python:

> The documentation for [%Z](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) says it matches `EST` among others, but in practice it doesn't.

Further down in the thread someone points out that:

> Looking at the code, the only timezone strings it recognizes are utc, gmt, and whatever is in time.tzname (EST and EDT, in my case).

(which might be why it works for you in REPL.)

The `MDT` timezone name is what it causing it to fail. You can confirm this by stripping it out. Try running this in Django shell and it will work:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('Fri May 13 2016 22:00:56 GMT-0600', 
                           '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z')
```

Possible solutions: strip out the last part of the time string before attempting to parse it; or use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) which works well:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse('Fri May 13 2016 22:00:56 GMT-0600 (MDT)')
```

Comment: That must be it. Plain Python had time.tzname set to `('MST', 'MDT')`. Django had it set to `('UTC', 'UTC')`. Dateutil also seems like it could be very useful. Thanks!